# How to Instrumenting application for prometheus monitoring in large codebase as a devops engineer

Tags: prometheus, instrumentation, icinga

what I've found in the internet regarding instrumenting application for prometheus monitoring is, people are instrumenting their app (python, go) by hard coding the application. So, they are all developers. From the devops perspective, how to instrument a huge application?

I am a DevOps engineer not a developer. I want to instrument company's current app which back end is C++ and 200+ developers are working on it. I have to monitor SOAP, GUI, DWM, TENENT, IFS etc. How can I plan my workflow?
Note: Currently it is monitored by Icinga, planned to move to prometheus, Grafana.

Answer (score 0):

As a DevOps engineer you need to write exporters to fetching data from your services. So you should have a little development knowledge about Python or Golang.

You can check exporters list in [this](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/) page.

If no one has developed the exporter you need, you have to develop it yourself.

Finally, you should be able to extract metrics from your services and monitor them using Prometheus and Grafana.